# Сохранить параметр css в cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Всем привет. У меня есть элемент, свойство которого изменяется при нажатии на пользователем на определенную кнопку. А именно, ul которому присваивается display: none. Мне нужно, чтобы это сохранялось при перезагрузке страницы. Как с помощью cookie и jquery сохранять стиль элемента?

upd. Наверное, некорректно объяснил проблему, приведу все с примером кода.

```
$('.odz-toggle').after().next().css("display", "none"); // Убираем лишние блоки
$(".odz-toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('div').slideUp('normal');
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('normal');
}); // открываем нужный блок при нажатии на кнопку
```

Необходимо позицию нужного ul'a (открытый или закрытый) сохранить в cookie.

Comment: можно код HTML ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNPOaN

Comment: теперь при открывании 1-го ul'a остальные сворачиваются вместе с кнопками, но при обновлении страницы положение все так же сбрасывается.

Comment: проверьте код, я обновил в ответе, все работает как надо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создать куки с параметрами

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.cookie("background:","red");
})
```

Считать информацию из кукиз:

```
$.cookie("background:");
```

Ответ: к дополниному вопросу: Проверяем если елемент закрыт или открыт, затем пишем куки

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.odz-toggle').after().next().css("display", "none"); 

    var ter = $('.innersubmenu-ul');
    for(i =0; i < ter.length; i++)
    {      
       if($.cookie('visible'+i) != null)
       {
         $('.innersubmenu-ul').eq($.cookie('visible'+i)).css('display', "block");
       }
       if($.cookie('hidden'+i) != null)
       {
        $('.innersubmenu-ul').eq($.cookie('hidden'+i)).css("display", "none");
       }
    }

    $(".odz-toggle").click(function () {

        $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('div').slideUp('normal');

        var ind = $(this).parent().index();
        var open = $.cookie('visible'+ind);
        if(open == "null")
        {
            $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('normal');
            $.cookie("hidden"+ind ,null);
            $.cookie("visible"+ind ,$(this).parent().index());
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('normal');
            $.cookie("visible"+ind ,null);
            $.cookie("hidden"+ind ,$(this).parent().index());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

можно с проверкой : если есть куки навешивать стили на элемент, если нет - цеплять событие)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if(typeof $.cookie('namecookie') === null){
      $('кнопка').click(function(){
         $.cookie('namecookie',{'display:','none'});
         $('элемент').css({'display:','none'});
      });
  }else{
    $('элемент').css($.cookie('namecookie'));
  }
});
```